# Rails - No route matches "index" when testing controller create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, minitest

I have the following relationship:

```rb
class Story < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :characters
end

class Character < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :story, required: true
end
```

And the following routes:

```rb
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :stories do
    resources :characters
  end
end
```

Which ends up looking like this:

[image: routes]

In my `CharactersController` test, I have:

```rb
test "can create a new character" do
  params = { story_id: @story.id, character: { name: "Billy" } }
  
  post(story_characters_path, params: params)

  # ... assertions follow
end
```

When it comes to the `post(...)` command, I receive:

`DRb::DRbRemoteError: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"characters"}, missing required keys: [:story_id]`

It seems to be attempting the index action instead of the create action, despite the `post`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to call a nested POST or PATCH action is:

```
post story_characters_path(story_id: @story.id),
       params: { 
         character: { name: "Billy" }
       }
```

While `post(story_characters_path(params))` might work you're actually putting the parameters into the query string instead of the request body where they should be.

In most cases you won't actually notice any difference as Rails merges the query string parameters with the request body into the params object but its still something that could let subtile bugs slip through.

For example if its a JSON request you won't get the correct types on the other end since query string parameters are always treated as strings.

Comment: Thanks, you are 100% correct.  My solution was not the correct one :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  I needed to change the lines:

```
params = { story_id: @story.id, character: { name: "Billy" } }
post(story_characters_path, params: params)
```

to:

```rb
params = { story_id: @story.id, character: { story_id: @story.id, name: "Billy" } }
post(story_characters_path(params))
```

[EDIT]: This isn't quite correct, as Max pointed out above. His solution is the correct one